# jquery counter stops after page refresh

Tags: jquery, browser

my code for live counter of a table.

```
jQuery(function($){
  setInterval(function(){
    $.get( 'counter.php', function(newRowCount){
      $('#mycounter').html( newRowCount );
    });
  },1000); // 1000ms == 1 seconds
});

<span id='mycounter'></span>
```

counter.php

```
include 'mysqli.php';

$result = $t->query("SELECT count(*) AS c FROM data");

$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

echo $row['c'];
```

but after i refresh the page or go to another page and come back it doesnt work. It gives me a blank with no counts. I think its due to the cache of the page because if I open it in incognito I don't have this issue.

whats a work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setting the cache option to false :

```
jQuery(function($){
  setInterval(function(){
      $.ajax({
          url   : 'counter.php',
          cache : false
      }).done(function(newRowCount) {
          $('#mycounter').html( newRowCount );
      });
  },1000); // 1000ms == 1 seconds
});
```

Comment: Awesome! didn't know that was possible. Thanks!